# How can I set the "Pick" flag for a bunch of photos based on filename in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, batch

I need to re-export some old photos with different settings (quality/size/etc.). Usually that's pretty straightforward: Enable a filter to show only picked photos, select all, export.

However, in one collection I do not have any photos marked as "picked" for some reason (maybe I exported everything and deleted bad photos afterwards... or the information got lost somehow). I still have the "good" JPEGs though.

Now I'd like to set the "pick" flag for all photos where a JPEG file exists (or whose filenames are in some list) - that's about 100 out of 700 photos so doing it manually for each photo is not an option. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a *Smart Collection* matching the filenames. I just had to copy all JPG filenames into an editor, remove the `.JPG`, and replace linebreaks with simple spaces.

To avoid collisions with other files in my catalog (since the filenames of my camera reset after 9999 photos) I also filtered by folder.

Afterwards I could simply select all photos in the collection and set the pick flag.